# How to render React component with react-router-dom by manually use of HTML5 history API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm converting an app (previously in jQuery/HTML/CSS) to React. The app has many modules, and each module has many submodules. I'm progressively trying to upgrade each submodule to React. The problem is that the sidebar is not in React.

There are two submodules which I have converted to React. The problem is when someone clicks on the sidebar link the entire page reloads and the resources going to fetch again.

If someone has open any one of the two pages that I have converted to React and then tries to move to the other page (also written in React) it should not reload for it. It should work like they are using the `Link` component to move.

I was thinking to mimic the feature by using the HTML5 history API. Using `history.pushState` did change the URL but react-router is not rendering the respective component on that URL.

I know there is some workaround with `HashRouter`, but instead, I want to use `BrowserRouter`.

For both pages, I'm rendering the same template from the backend and the routing logic delegated to react-router.

For started, I have created a [**codesandbox demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqjyx7y6wl). Please tweak it and try to make it work when clicking on the (without `Link`) URLs as the `Link` component behaves in react-router.